# Exercise 9 Chapter III from Kunen's Set theory: An intro to independence proofs

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

(9) Show in ZF: AC is equivalent to $\forall$ $\alpha$(P($\alpha$)) can be well-ordered. Hint: Show by induction on $\alpha$ that R($\alpha$) can be well-ordered.

PROOF: By induction on $\alpha$.

Case i. $\alpha$ = $\emptyset$ ; then R($\alpha$) = R($\emptyset$) = $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ is well-ordered trivially.

Case ii. $\alpha$ = R($\beta$ + 1) where $\beta$ is an ordinal. Suppose for induction hypothesis all $\beta$ < $\alpha$ are well-ordered, to show $\alpha$ is well-ordered.Then R($\alpha$) = R ($\beta$ + 1) = P(R($\beta$)). If P(R($\beta$)) is not well-ordered, there is no least member of P(R($\beta$)). But $\beta$ is well-ordered by hypothesis, guaranteeing a least member given R($\beta$). Contradiction. So  P(R($\beta$)) must be well-ordered after all.

Case iii. $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. Then R($\alpha$) = $\bigcup$R($\beta$) for $\beta$ < $\alpha$, and must be well-ordered since every constituent of the union is well-ordered.

END PROOF.

Ballpark? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Specifically, see Camilo Arosemena's answer there.

Comment: I don't really understand your case ii, and for case iii, there's a difference between $R(\alpha)$ can be well-ordered and $R(\alpha)$ IS well-ordered. Without AC, you can't arbitrarily select a well-ordering for each constituent of the union.

Comment: Thanks Asaf! Much appreciated.